# Kivy dynamic background loading not functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

The goal is a screen which uses one of several images (randomly chosen upon each screen load) as a background.

The app contains the following:

```
class AnswerScreen(Screen):
    bkgd = ""
    def choose_bkgd(self):
        self.bkgd = "{}.jpg".format(random.randint(0,8))
```

My kv file contains the following:

```
<AnswerScreen>
    on_pre_enter: root.choose_bkgd()
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: root.bkgd
```

Unfortunately the background is always just a solid white.
I've added a print call to `choose_bkgd()`, and it always prints an acceptable file name, and I've also tried using `on_enter:` but there is no change. If I replace source: with a file name instead of root.bkgd the image displays correctly. This leads me to believe that the background is being generated before the function is being called to set the bkgd variable, but this confuses me as I thought the whole point of `on_pre_enter` was to execute code prior to the loading of the screen. The kivy docs haven't cleared this up for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make bkgd a kivy property. This is essential to be able to bind to it and have things automatically update when it changes.

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
class AnswerScreen(Screen):
    bkgd = StringProperty("")
...
```

Comment: Gah! I'm new to kivy and there are a few things that I just don't seem to be able to beat into my little brain. Thank you.